# Задача на С++ "Книга"

Tags: c++

## Книга

Миша иногда читал книги. Но и это он делал странным способом: начинал он всегда с первой страницы и читал ежедневно ровно столько страниц, сколько равна сумма цифр номера страницы, с которой он начинал читать в соответствующий день. То есть, в первый день он читал одну страницу, потом две, четыре, восемь и так далее. Помогите отцу Миши выяснить, какой день его сын читает книгу, если сейчас Миша читает k-ую страницу книги.

## Входные данные:

Номер страницы k (0 < k < 5000), которую сейчас читает Миша.

## Выходные данные:

Номер дня, который Миша читает книгу.

## Мой код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,d=0,x, sum=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int s=1;
        x=sum;
        if(sum<10){
        sum=sum+sum;
        }
        else {
            while(x!=0){
            sum+=sum%10;
            x/=10;
            }
        }
        sum=sum+s;
        if(sum>=n){
        d++;
        cout<<d;
        return 0;
        }
        else d++;
    }
}
```

## Вопрос:

Почему при проверке только 30%? Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Очень смущает `while(x!=0){
            sum+=sum%10;
            x/=10;
            }` - что-то странное вычисляется, нет? кстати. дайте URL поиграться...

Comment: @Harry вычисляется сума цифр числа которое больше или равно 10

Comment: Что-то я не понял условие, если:  сколько равна сумма цифр номера страницы - то почему последовательность такая: он читал одну страницу, потом две, четыре, восемь и так далее? Если я не туплю, то "сумма цифр номера страницы" - это сумма цифр номера страницы... Тобишь если страница 3, то сумма 3, а если 12, то тоже 3. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: 1 -> `1+1=2` -> `2+2=4` -> `4+4=8` -> `8+8=16` -> `16+1+6=23` -> `23+2+3=28`...

Comment: Всё таки наверное `sum+=x%10`?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch так я тоже не до конца понял условие

Comment: он начинал читать всегда с первой страницы...   с которой он начинал читать в соответствующий день.. Я ничего не понел

Comment: @vp_arth так это сумма цифр номера страницы + номер страницы

Comment: @MRX а вы точно переписали условие?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, "начинал читать книгу с первой страницы" и "начинал продолжать чтение"

Comment: @vp_arth а, все, допер

Comment: так если он всегда начинал читать с первой страницы, то во первых он тупой и во вторых может и я тупой, что ничего не понел, всеравно

Comment: Про первую страницу - это начальные условия для первого дня. Зачем придираться к формулировке? Если бы он каждый день читал первую страницу, то как отец определит какой день он читает книгу?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch да

Comment: @vp_arth,  я не придираюсь, просто хочу понять что нужно считать. Может нужно просто вывести k тый  член  числа Фибонначи

Comment: @Harry https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/contests/10039/problems/91250

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main()
{
  int n, day = 1, sum = 1; // переменная s не нужна, 1 страница - просто инициализация
  cin>>n;
  if (n == 1) {
    cout << day;
    return 0;
  }
  while(true){
    int x = sum;
    // x < 10 не является специальным случаем
    while(x!=0){
      sum += x % 10; // Ошибка! всегда считалась только последняя цифра суммы
      x /= 10;
    }
    day++; // операции, выполняющиеся безусловно стоит выносить из условия
    if(sum >= n){
      cout << day;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно изменить цикл на `while(sum<n)` и вынести вывод из цикла, но старался ближе к коду в вопросе

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вот решение:

```
#include<iostream>

int sum(int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size {};
    std::cout << "Input size:\n";
    std::cin >> size;
    int day {1};
    for(int i {1}; i <= size; ++day) {
        i += sum(i);
    }

    std::cout << --day << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int sum(int x)
{
    int s {};
    if (x / 10) {
        s += x % 10;
        return s += sum(x / 10);
    }
    else {
        return s += x;
    }
}
```